# How to add elimination mechanism in Python genetic algorithm based on DEAP

Tags: python, algorithm, genetic-algorithm, deap

Here is my question.
I'm dealing with one optimization problem using DEAP.

For now, I use `toolbox.register("select", tools.selNSGA2)` to select some fittest indivual to survive.

But I want to add some threshold by user-defined function.

Can the algorithm achieve two step of selection?

> 1. Select several individuals by the tournament or selNSGA2 method
> 2. Eliminate several individuals by pre-defined thresholds.

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
def myselect(pop, k, check):
    return [ind for in in tools.selNSGA2(pop, k) if check(ind)]

def mycheck(ind):
    return True

toolbox.register("select", myselect, check=mycheck)
```

However, you will end up selecting <= k offspring.

Comment: Or you could run `mycheck` on all of the individuals, then select `k` offspring from those, if selecting <k offspring is a problem